Hashing data in Varnish 7 open-source
Is there a way to hash a string in the OS version of Varnish 7? For example using SHA256.
Basically I need an equivalent of this:
import digest;

sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.url);
    hash_data(req.http.Host);

    if (req.http.Client-Cert) {
        hash_data(digest.hash_sha256(req.http.Client-Cert));
    }

    return (lookup);
}

but the digest VMOD is from the enterprise version and not found in the OS edition :/
I'm using the Docker version to be precise.

You can find the source code here: https://github.com/varnish/libvmod-digest.
You'll have to compile it from source yourself though. Varnish Enterprise packages this VMOD for your convenience.
However vmod_digest isn't even Varnish Enterprise's main cryptographic VMOD. vmod_crypto actually has a lot more to offer.
If you can compile vmod_digest yourself, you'll probably be fine. If you need help, just contact Varnish Software here: https://www.varnish-software.com/contact-us/
